# Spring Batch job processing for multiple files but one file at a time

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job, I need to read multiple text files from a folder.
The requirement is like :-
I need to read one file and if there are more than 300 lines of entry then I need to set the chunk size as 300 and write the same in database.
If its less than 300 then I need to set the chunk size as the number of lines of code and write in database.
Then I need to read the next file and write in database untill all the files in folder are consumed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for a partitioned step. In general, you'd have your `Partitioner` identify the files to process. It will spin off create child steps, each of which will process a single child. For those child steps you'd set the chunk size to 300 (the framework will automatically commit when it reaches the end of the file or any multiple of 300).

You also need to set a task executor for the child steps. In your case, since you only want to process one file at a time, the `SyncTaskExecutor` is a good fit.

For more information, please see the [Spring Batch documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html) or [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/).